# gcloud: The user does not have access to service account "default"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, service-accounts

I attempting to use an activated service account scoped to create and delete gcloud container clusters (k8s clusters), using the following commands:

```
gcloud config configurations create my-svc-account \
   --no-activate \
   --project myProject


gcloud auth activate-service-account my-svc-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
   --key-file=/path/to/keyfile.json \
   --configuration my-svc-account

gcloud container clusters create a-new-cluster \
   --configuration my-svc-account \
   --project= my-project
   --zone "my-zone"
```

I always receive the error:

```
...ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.create) ResponseError: code=400, message=The user does not have access to service account "default".
```

How do I grant my-svc-account access to the default service account for GKE?

Comment: Note that `gcloud config configurations create my-svc-account --no-activate --project myproject` does not set project in created configuration. In fact --project does not do anything.

Answer (score 35):

After talking to Google Support, the issue was that the service account did not have a "Service Account User" permissions activated. Adding "Service Account User" resolves this error.

Comment: Cheers. This definitely did it.
Only thing to note is that the role is now called "Service Account User".

Comment: for more info on the above point see https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#the_service_account_actor_role

Comment: you just saved my nervous system. Thank you

Answer (score 14):

Add the following **role** to the service account who makes the operation:

`Service Account User`

Also see:

- https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/iam#service_account_user
- https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#the_service_account_user_role
- https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles

Comment: work well for me, my case, I call `ssh` from Google Cloud Build to Google Engine VM Instance

Answer (score 1):

For those that ended up here trying to do an [Import of Firebase Firestore documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import) with a command such as:

`gcloud beta firestore import --collection-ids='collectionA','collectionB' gs://YOUR_BUCKET`

I got around the issue by doing the following:

1. From the [Google Cloud Console Storage Bucket Browser](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/), add the service account completing the operation to the list of *members* with a role of `Storage Admin`.
2. Re-attempt the operation.

For security, I revoked the role after the operation completed, but that's optional.

Answer (score 1):

`iam.serviceAccounts.actAs` is the exact permission you need from `Service Account User`

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the `The user does not have access to service account...` error even though I added the `Service Account User` role as others have [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40556296/2016436#2016436). What I was missing was the organization policy that prevented service account impersonation across projects. This is explained in the docs: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/impersonating-service-accounts#enabling-cross-project

Comment: FYI: I was not able to "see" this policy in the UI at https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/orgpolicies/list but according to https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/configure-user-specified-service-accounts#cross-project_set_up it is enabled by default ("In the project that has your user-specified service account, ensure that the iam.disableCrossProjectServiceAccountUsage organization policy constraint is not enforced. This constraint is enforced by default.")

Comment: Follow-Up: I was able to see it in the UI when selecting the affected project (previously I had the organization selected as project). To disable it, I needed the role "Organization Policy Administrator" and it can be disabled "per project" (so not for the whole org) via `https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/orgpolicies/iam-disableCrossProjectServiceAccountUsage/edit?project=$home-project-of-service-account`

After a couple of minutes the change became effective and the (misleading) error went away

Answer (score 0):

Added *Service Account User* role to service account and it worked for me.