# ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.create) ResponseError: code=400, message=The user does not have access to service account "default"

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a gcp service account with kubernetes engine admin role, I get an error trying to create new cluster. Any ideas?

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file service_account.json
gcloud config set project my_proj_name
gcloud container clusters create dummy  --num-nodes=3  -m n1-standard-8 --zone europe-west1-b

ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.create) ResponseError: code=400, message=The user does not have access to service account "default".
```

.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40367866/gcloud-the-user-does-not-have-access-to-service-account-default

Answer (score 4):

Issue solved after setting the service account role to the 'Editor' since kubernetes Engine Admin was not sufficient to create new cluster.

Answer (score 1):

Seems your user does not have access to the service account or service account does not have the right role. You can check [service account user role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#the_service_account_user_role) to your user and give Editor, compute admin and service account actor roles.

Answer (score -1):

gcloud container clusters create demo-cluster --num-nodes=2 --subnetwork=default  use this

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).